# Constructor de clase solo crea un objecto

Tags: php, poo

En el siguiente codigo hay dos clases jugador y equipo, se imprime un formulario para añadir un nombre, una vez escrito el nombre crea correctamente un jugador pero **si quiero crear otro jugador sobreescribe el anterior ya creado.**

En la ultima parte del codigo intento listar los jugadores con un foreach recorriendo el array de jugador pero no me sale ningún jugador.

```
class Jugador {

     private $nombre;

    function __construct($nombre) {

          $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

     function getNombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}


class Equipo{

    public $jugador = array();

    function __construct() {

    }

     // Funcion para añadir los jugadores creados al array $jugador.
    function addJugador($unJugador){
        $this->jugador[]=$unJugador;
    }
}

function imprimeFormulario(){

    echo '<FORM ACTION = "prueba.php" METHOD = "GET" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 73px;">
                <h2>Añadir Jugador </h2>
                <label>Introduce el nombre : </label><INPUT class="form" TYPE = "text" NAME = "nombre"> <br>
                <INPUT TYPE = "hidden" NAME = "action" VALUE = "recordData"><br>
                <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "Enviar">
            </ FORM>';
}


// Si se pulsa el boton enviar...
if ($_GET['action'] == "recordData") {

    // Se utiliza el constructor del objecto jugador para crear un jugador(*solo crea un jugador*).
    $jugadores = new Jugador($_GET['nombre']);

    // Si vuelvo instanciar Jugador con otra variable si que crea otro jugador, hay alguna forma de crear los jugadores instanciando una sola vez?
    //$jugadores2 = new Jugador($_GET['nombre']);
}

// Instanciar objecto equipo.
$elEquipo=new Equipo();

// Se guarda el jugar en el array $jugador.
$elEquipo->addJugador($jugadores);

var_dump($elEquipo);

// Imprime formulario para añadir a un jugador en el array $jugador.
imprimeFormulario();

// Listar los jugadores guardados en el array $jugador (*no funciona*).
foreach ( $jugador as $jugadores ) {

    echo $jugadores;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Tu variable `$juadores` no es un *array* ni nada, es una variable simple. ¿ Como esperas que almacene mas de 1 valor ?

Comment: Aaaaaahhhh, vale: ¿ quieres que almacene los distintos jugadores **en sucesivas llamadas** al *script* ?

Comment: Sí @Trauma, el código solo añade un jugador para añadir otro tendría que instanciar de nuevo la clase jugador pero eso es algo que querría evitar. Gracias.

Comment: Pero, si te he entendido bien ... ¿ como pretendes hacerlo sin almacenarlo en algún sitio **externo** a tu *script* ? Desde el punto de vista de PHP, cada solicitud es completamente independiente de la otra; vamos, que PHP no tiene *memoria*.

Comment: Como comenta @Trauma, no puedes guardar varios jugadores en sucesivas llamadas al script. Es necesario hacer que los datos *persistan* de alguna forma (lo más común es en una base de datos), o en localStorage del lado del cliente (en ese caso no tiene mucho sentido querer pasar los datos al servidor)... O bien recoger en el formulario los datos de todos los jugadores del equipo, mandarlos en una sola llamada y ahí sí podrás crear todos los objetos `Jugador` y pasarlos luego como un array a `Equipo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira hice un ejemplo comprobable de lo que realmente quieres hacer, existen algunas lagunas en tu codigo por ejemplo puedes añadir n jugadores al equipo pero debes tener alguna manera de almacenarlos para posteriormente leerlo, despues que hagas la petición al servidor, existen unas cuantas, puedes usar la session, una base de datos, o un fichero. En este ejemplo que te pongo use la session de php y separe la logica en 2 archivos 1 lamado clases.php donde declaro las 2 clases que ya tenias pero le añadi algunas cosas nuevas, y las funciones principales de tu aplicacion. El otro archivo es prueba.php donde esta la entrada a tu pagina.

**Clases.php**

```
class Jugador {

    private $nombre;

    public function __construct($nombre) 
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    public function getNombre() 
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}


class Equipo{

    private $jugadores;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->jugadores = array();
    }

     // Funcion para añadir los jugadores creados al array $jugador.
    // Con esto puedes añadir mas de un jugador seria algo como
    // $equipo->addJugador($a)->addJugador($b);
    public function addJugador($unJugador)
    {
        $this->jugadores[] = $unJugador;

        return $this;
    }

    //Imprime el listado de los jugadores
    public function printJugadores()
    {
        foreach($this->jugadores as $jugador){
            echo $jugador.'<br />';
        }
    }
}

function imprimirFormulario()
{
     echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 73px;">
                <h2>Añadir Jugador </h2>
                <label>Introduce el nombre : </label><INPUT class="form" TYPE = "text" NAME = "nombre"> <br><br>
                <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "Agregar" name="action">
                <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "Listar" name="action">
            </ FORM>';
}

//Carga los datos del equipo de la sesion y si no existe crea un nuevo equipo
function cargarEquipo()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['equipo']) ? $_SESSION['equipo'] : new Equipo();
}


//Guarda los datos del equipo en la sesion
function salvarEquipo($equipo)
{
   $_SESSION['equipo'] = $equipo;
}
```

**Este seria el prueba.php**
Debo aclarar que si creas un formulario y el action va para la misma página no debes especificar el atributo **ACTION** y lo segundo a aclarar es que siempre que puedas pasa los datos por **POST**, primero pk estas creando algo y segundo porque la url se mantiene sin cambios no se le añaden los query. Bien aki te dejo el resto

```
require_once 'clases.php';

imprimirFormulario();

$equipo = cargarEquipo();

//unset($_SESSION['equipo']);

if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
        case 'Agregar':
            $equipo->addJugador(new Jugador($_POST['nombre']));
            salvarEquipo($equipo);
            break;

        case 'Listar':
            echo '<hr />';
            $equipo->printJugadores(); 
            //var_dump(isset($_SESSION['equipo']) ? $_SESSION['equipo']: '');           
            break;
    } 
}
```

**OJO** Puedes probar cerrar y abrir la pestaña y veras que el listado se mantiene ya la parte de borrarlos o editarlos te lo dejo a ti jejeje